# Is it possible to convert a timestamp to human readable date (in any language) with CodeIgniter 3.1.9

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, timestamp, codeigniter-3

Is it possible to convert a timestamp to human readable date (in any language) with CodeIgniter 3.1.9.

As much as possibe, I would like to use helper (date helper).

- **Input** : 2018-11-01 17:12:26.
- **Output** : le 1er novembre 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date helper will not help you. Use the following function (also include conversion to local time):

```
function dateTimeToFrench($datetime, $format="l j F Y à H:i:s", $convertToLocalTime = false)
{
    $english_days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
    $french_days = array('lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi', 'dimanche');
    $english_months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    $french_months = array('janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre');

    $datetime = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    if ($convertToLocalTime) $datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
    return str_replace($english_months, $french_months, str_replace($english_days, $french_days, $datetime->format($format) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the helper function [nice_date](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html#nice_date) is what you want.

It takes two arguments the first is the input string the second is a format string. The format string uses the same scheme at PHP's `date()` function as documented [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

The `nice_date` function is deprecated and the docs suggest using PHP's [DateTime class](https://secure.php.net/datetime) instead, e.g.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat($input_format, $input)->format($output_format);
```

(My guess is the downvotes are related to that.)

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you for the constructive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **setlocale** and **strftime** functions, it might be possible. [Reference Link](http://www.thecreativedev.com/how-to-convert-date-in-other-language-in-php/)

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "de_DE"); //Setting the locale to German
echo strftime( "%h %y",strtotime("2011-12-22")); // Prints ‘Dez 2011’ month is in German
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works on my development environment, but not in production. Locals are not installed, and I don't have rights to install.

Comment: @Imabot Happy to helping you :) and in production you can try with php ini or else contact server support.